# Iphone development: codesign cannot access Keychain

Tags: iphone, keychain, codesign

I am stuck in the hell of keychain and iphone app certification process.

I have the `/usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1` error

I have tried everything including doing the process X thousand times from the beginning, checking the build and target settings, plist bundle id etc...

But one thing is surprising, when I build my application, the "`Allow access to keychain for codesign`" window appears for half a second and disappears, then the build error shows up.

I tried to modify the properties of the private key used to sign my application in the keychain Access to allow all applications (in the "access control" window). But when I save nothing happens, Keychain Access wont keep my modifications, whatever I do.

Comment: This is a question for http://superuser.com; the question is about how to use a tool, it's not about how to do something in a programming language.

Comment: I disagree completely, kiamlaluno. The question is related to building an application, which is most certainly programming related.

Comment: as Shaggy frog says, this is all hapening while trying to build an application in Xcode to export it on an iphone device.

Answer (score 1):

Ok it was a rights issue, I just created a new user and everything works fine.